# Como armazenar Strings em Vetores - C

Tags: c, char

Como eu faço para armazenar mais de um nome em uma variável do tipo ***char***, por que se colocar, vamos supor ***nome[20]***, eu tô definindo que ela recebera 20 caracteres, e não que ela poderá receber 20 elementos, o código que eu tô tentando testar isso, é esse aqui.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int i;
float tvendas[10], pvendas[10];
char nome[15];

int main(void){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O TOTAL DE VENDAS: R$ ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &tvendas[i]);

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O PERCENTUAL DE AUMENTO DAS VENDAS: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &pvendas[i]);

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O NOME: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", nome[i]);  // MEU PROBLEMA É AQUI

    }

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
    printf("TESTE %s\n", nome[i]); //TESTANDO PARA VER SE OS NOMES APARECEM.
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: nao seria, por exemplo: *char nome[15][15];*

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito obrigado, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso, brigadão.

Comment: blza, vou colocar como resposta pra facilitar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer um array bidimensional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int i;
float tvendas[10], pvendas[10];
char nome[15][15];

int main(void){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O TOTAL DE VENDAS: R$ ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &tvendas[i]);

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O PERCENTUAL DE AUMENTO DAS VENDAS: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &pvendas[i]);

        printf("%d° VENDEDOR | DIGITE O NOME: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", nome[i]);  // MEU PROBLEMA É AQUI

    }

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
    printf("TESTE %s\n", nome[i]); //TESTANDO PARA VER SE OS NOMES APARECEM.
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito !!

Comment: opa! que bom :)

Answer (score 4):

Para mostrar outra alternativa, e de certa forma como complemento à resposta do @aa_sp pode também utilizar um array de ponteiros para `char`. Neste cenário é necessario alocar cada nome individualmente no `for` antes de utilizar.

```
//...
char *nome[15]; //vetor de ponteiros para char (strings), 15 nomes

int main(void){
    //...
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        //...
        nome[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30); //aloca espaço uma string de 29 carateres
        scanf("%s", nome[i]); //scanf igual ao que tinha
    }

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        printf("TESTE %s\n", nome[i]); //printf também igual ao que tinha
    }
    //...
```

Para o exemplo que você tem, a solução de alocar em *stack* como a resposta do @aa_sp mostrou é preferível pois é mais rápido, simples e evita ter de liberar memória quando não necessitar mais das strings.

Este forma que eu mostrei é util em pelo menos dois cenários:

1. Quando cria as strings numa função e necessita que elas existam para além do tempo de vida da função
2. Se pretender que o espaço reservado para cada nome seja diferente.

Como nota final utilizei `sizeof(char)` apenas para tornar claro que é o tamanho do `char` que está a servir de suporte ao `malloc` ainda que seja garantido que resulte sempre em `1`.

Comment: acho que este seria o "jeito C" de fazer, usando array de ponteiros, porque na "vida real" (fora do StackOverflow em português) nunca vi um array bidimensional ser usado em C...

Comment: Muito obrigado, tenho que estudar sobre esses ponteiros também, usando a forma do aa_sp funcionou em bastantes exercícios, porém em alguns, está juntando um nome com o outro vamos supor, Paulo e Vitor quando eu coloco um printf para mostrar os nomes fica PaVitor, tenho que arrumar um jeito de arrumar isso.